# Prove that a set a closed.

Tags: general-topology

I have been given the set:

$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : r^2 \leq x^2+y^2\leq R^2,z^2 \in [\epsilon,1]\}$.

For $0 \leq r \leq R$ and $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.

I believe this set is closed (it is definitely not open),  however, I'm pretty stuck as to how to show that it is closed.

I've tried to show that it contains all of its limit points, but this seems very very difficult. I've also tried to show that its complement is open but this too is hard.

Is there some other way that I could show that it is closed more concisely?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in \overline{F}$, where $F=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : r^2 \leq x^2+y^2\leq R^2,z^2 \in [\epsilon,1]\}$ and a sequence $\{(x_n,y_n,z_n)\} \subset F$ such that $(x_n,y_n,z_n) \rightarrow (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: With F bar do you mean the complement?

Comment: @Delansi The closure of $F$.

Comment: So this way I can show somehow that $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is inside $F$ itself?

Comment: Yes, use the fact that each entry in the sequence converges to the corresponding limit combined with the fact that if $a_n\to a$ and $a_n \leq (\geq C)$ then $a \leq (\geq C)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x.y,z)= x^2+y^2$ and $g(x,y,z)=z^2$ are both continuous functions on $\Bbb R^3$.
Your set equals $$f^{-1}[[r^2,R^2]] \cap g^{-1}[[\varepsilon, 1]]$$ by definition. This is an intersection of inverse images of closed sets under continuous maps, so closed.